# Aumentar desempenho de script PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho

Boa Tarde

Atualmente, tenho um script em PHP que le um arquivo CSV de 6801 linhas, e realiza um INSERT enquanto houver registros. Estou conseguindo inserir atualmente 19 registros por segundo.

Além dessa rotina de INSERT que roda a cada 5 minutos, os usuário vão conectar na base de dados e etc..

Gostaria de alguma forma para aumentar a taxa de 19reg/seg e ainda fazer com que conexões simultâneas também tenham um bom desempenho.

Segue o fonte da função de leitura:

```
 error_reporting(0);
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 set_time_limit(600);
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "datab";

$conecta = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or print (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($database, $conecta) or print(mysql_error()); 

function lerCsv(){



$handle = fopen("csv.csv", "r");
$num = 1;
$inicio = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
Logger("Inicio da insercao -> ".$inicio);
while (!feof($handle) ) {
    $linhas = fgetcsv($handle, 0);       
    $a= $linhas[0];
    $b= $linhas[1];
    $c= $linhas[2];
    $d= $linhas[3];
    $e= $linhas[4];
    $f= $linhas[5];


    $sql = "insert into bldatant values(null, '".$a."', '".$b."','".$c."','".$d."','".$e."','".$f."');";
    if($query = mysql_query($sql)){
        Logger("Registro ".$num." inserido com sucesso.".$sql);
        $num++;

    }
    else{
        Logger("Erro ao inserir registro".$num.". Erro->".mysql_error());
    }

    $sql="update blparams set valorparam=NOW() where nomeparam='BP_LASTUPD'";
    $exc = mysql_query($sql);


}

fclose($handle);
mysql_close($conecta);
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código fonte, uma séria de coisas podem influenciar isso.

Comment: @rray adicionado :)

Comment: Existem uma série de ajustes que poderiam ser empregadas, uma seria fazer o insert direto ao banco eliminando o arquivo cvs, com um web service por exemplo, outra medida seria melhorar o hardware colocar um HD SSD, dar uma olhada nos status e ver o que é gargalho no seu banco e ajustar via hardware ou ajustar o arquivo de configuração do banco de dados ( tunning ) são tantas possibilidades que seria melhor você especificar que tipo de ajuste gostaria de aplicar

Comment: Estude sobre como fazer operações em lotes no MySQL (bulk insert, bulk update). Basicamente você desabilita o auto-commit para a conexão atual, faz um lote de, sei lá, 100 operações por vez, e então dá um commit só. Isso agiliza bastante as coisas quando o número de inserts/updates seguidos é grande.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Atualmente estou rodando na minha máquina, i5 com 4Gb de RAM, futuramente, ele irá para uma hospedagem online, provavelmente Locaweb, de forma que não tenho como mexer no hardware. Creio que seja melhor mesmo ajustes em código e banco de dados

Comment: @Piovezan vou dar uma olhada sobre isso, mas desabilitando o auto commit eu não corro nenhum risco de perder as transações?

Comment: O auto commit serve para dar commit automaticamente após cada insert/update, ou seja, fazer a operação valer. Ao desabilitá-lo, você tem que dar commit explicitamente via código após cada lote de inserts/updates (esse lote, ou seja o que acontece entre um commit e outro, é o que se chama de transação). Feito isso você volta a habilitar o auto commit caso tenha alguma outra operação a fazer, caso contrário isso não é necessário. Ele só vale para a conexão que você está usando no momento, não interfere em outras conexões. Aprenda também o rollback, que desfaz a transação caso algo dê errado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma vez que não efectuas qualquer processamento dos dados do ficheiro, não vejo necessidade alguma para processar o ficheiro de forma sequencial.

Assim, em minha opinião, podes remover o ciclo (laço) e processar o ficheiro de uma vez com o [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html). Por exemplo:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'csv.csv'
        INTO TABLE bldatant
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
        (a, b, c, d, d, f)
        SET ID=NULL"
```

Tens apenas que substituir (a, b, c, d, d, f) pelos nomes das colunas da tua tabela e ID pelo nome da coluna à qual estás a atribuir o valor NULL.

Caso encontres ainda assim problemas de performance, podes alterar as definições de [bulk insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size). Por exemplo:

```
set bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
```

Comment: Você dia substituir a, b, c, d, e, f pelo nome das colunas da tabela no banco e ID pela minha chave primaria?Além disso, existe alguma maneira de medir a velocidade usando o LOAD DAtA INFILE?

Comment: Sim, substituir a, b, c, d, e, f pelas colunas da tabela e ID pela chave primária. Podes usar a função microtime() para medir o tempo que demora a carregar o ficheiro na totalidade.

Comment: Sim, uso auto increment default, de 1 em 1

Comment: @LucasTorres, Para medir a performance pode usar a função microtime().

Comment: Bruno, esse é um exemplo de uma das linhas:                                         06-21-2015 00:00:30,A63510,,"-22.86771","-43.258751",0                         Note que alguns dados estão entre aspas, teria algum problema?

Comment: @LucasTorres, editei a resposta. Podes usar a opção OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'

Comment: Funcionou! Apenas alterei para                                                       LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'csv.csv' 
INTO TABLE bldatant 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(a, b, c, d, d, f)
 SET ID=NULL"